# How to nest HtmlHelpers

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I would like to pass a value to my controller action from Html.ActionLink.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click to open/download", "DownloadResource", "Admin", new { URL = <%= Model.TargetResource %> }, null)%>
```

But if I use **<%= Model.TargetResource %>**, I get a syntax error. 
What should be the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click to open/download", "DownloadResource", "Admin", new { URL = Model.TargetResource }, null)%>
```

Comment: Also, is it possible to pass a default value to URL if Model.TargetResource value is null?

Comment: You can use the null coalescing operator: `<%= Html.ActionLink("Click to open/download", "DownloadResource", "Admin", new { URL = Model.TargetResource ?? "...default" }, null)%>`

Answer (score 0):

You're already in a code block, so you don't need to use `<% %>` within the code block.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click to open/download", 
                    "DownloadResource", 
                    "Admin", 
                    new { URL = Model.TargetResource }, 
                    null)%>
```